# how to get the nodes with specific element value

Tags: xml, xpath, nsxmlparser, nodes, touchxml

Could some one please tell me how do we use the text function in the
XPath query.
I needed the information for Hillman Library present in the xml

http://www.sis.pitt.edu/~arazeez/Librarydata.xml

```
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Library[1]/Hours/TermOrHolidays" error:nil];.
```

for now I used the [1]. But I wanted to use the text function

```
NSString *libName = @"Hillman Library";
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Library[LibraryName/text() = libName]/Hours/TermOrHolidays" error:nil];
```

But this is not working out. Could some one please let me know how I
go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Abdul. Welcome to SO. Highlight code and press ctrl-k to format properly.

Answer (score 2):

> But I wanted to use the text function
>
> ```
>  NSString *libName = @"Hillman Library";  
>  resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Library[LibraryName/text() = libName]/Hours/TermOrHolidays" error:nil];
> ```
>
> But this is not working out

**The problem is that**:

`//Library[LibraryName/text() = libName]/Hours/TermOrHolidays`

selects all `Library` elements in the document one of the text-node children of which is equal to one of the `libName` children of that same `Library`.

The `Library` elements in the referenced XML document don't have any `libName` children, and this is why the above XPath expression selects nothing.

**You want**:

`//Library[LibraryName/text() = 'Hillman Library']/Hours/TermOrHolidays`

**or**

`//Library[LibraryName/text() = "Hillman Library"]/Hours/TermOrHolidays`

Either quotes or apostrophes can be used.

In an XPath expression a string is specified by surrounding it with quotes or apostrophes. XPath doesn't understand the variables of its hosting language.

Answer (score 0):

Ah..thanks for that Dimitre... It worked out.
Like you said XPath doesnt understand the variable of its hosting language. So can I concatenate and form an XPath query and then use it.

```
NSString *libName = @"Engineering Library";
    NSMutableString  *xpathquery = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [xpathquery appendString:@"//Library[LibraryName/text() = '"];
    [xpathquery appendString:libName];
    [xpathquery appendString:@"']/../Hours/TermOrHolidays"];
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:xpathquery error:nil];
```

I am new to C-objective and still struggling with simple concepts`enter code here`

Comment: I tried using this as well but in vain. Getting some error.

NSString *string1 = @"//LibraryName[text() = '";
 NSString *string2 = @"']/../Hours/TermOrHolidays";
 NSString *newString;
 NSString *newString1;
 newString = [string1 stringByAppendingString:libName];
 newString1 = [newString stringByAppendingString:string2];
 NSLog(newString1);
 //correct one below
 //resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//LibraryName[text()= 'Engineering Library']/../Hours/TermOrHolidays" error:nil];
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodeForXPath:newString1 error:nil];